# is there a function to do action on 3 textboxes after submitting in specific time Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i will try to explain this because it seems complicated. i have 3 Textbox inputs, i want do action on the first input then after some time automatically the same action be on the second input, after the same time, the action  on the third input.

```
        <form action="@Url.Action("ShowResults")" id="sideForm" method="post" onsubmit="return SidebarValidation()" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstInput" autocomplete="off" name="first" placeholder="Enter Keyword..." value="@Request["first"]"  required><br /><hr />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondInput" autocomplete="off" name="second" placeholder="Enter Keyword..." value="@Request["second"]" ><br /><hr />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thirdInput" autocomplete="off" name="third" placeholder="Enter Keyword..." value="@Request["third"]" ><br /><hr />
        <div class="col"><button type="submit" id="sdSubmit" name="sideSubmit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-family: poppins">Custom SEARCH</button></div>
    </form>
```

this is the view.cshtml,  as you see i have 3 inputs and submit button, when i click the button i want an action executed on the first input and after 5 minutes the second input and after 5 minute the third input and after 5 minutes the first input again an so on.

if anyone has a clue please help !

Comment: "i want an action executed", a controller `Action` or do you just want to do something after 5mins?

Comment: there are some if conditions in action controller i want to be executed on those inputs after 5min.

Comment: I would investigate [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) and see if that meets your needs.

Comment: thank you steve i appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. Run this console application, extract the things you need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
namespace FileAdda
{
    public class Example
    {
        static string globalstr = "";
        static List<string> list = new List<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //assume these as your input values.
            list.Add("Value 1");
            list.Add("Value 2");
            list.Add("Value 3");
            Run();
        }
        public static void Run()
        {
            // You can set it to whatever time you want.
            int seconds = 5 * 1000;
            var timer = new Timer(TimerMethod, null, 0, seconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Put your logic in this method.
        public static void TimerMethod(object o)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(globalstr))
            {
                globalstr = list.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                int lastindex = list.IndexOf(globalstr);
                if (lastindex == (list.Count - 1))
                {
                    globalstr = list[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    globalstr = list[lastindex + 1];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"The timer callback for {globalstr}");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can the Run() function takes parametres or not, because i'm getting data from the view to controller.

Comment: You can directly access values in method TimerMethod() and then call it from Run().